# Allow scrollbar to overlap?

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll

I've got a site with 3 pages, one of which has a scrollbar. When switching between a page without and the page with the scrollbar, the navigation bar changes places, and the transition looks terrible. This is because I have a css/div-based layout, and it centers itself on the window. So, since it will only be covering white space, is there a way to make the scrollbar sit on top of the page, instead of shrinking the page to be next to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't place the scrollbar over the page, but you can force it to be shown on all pages, so there will be no jumps:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hadn't considered that, thanks! "You can accept an answer in 10 minutes" is Stack Exchange's singular flaw.